# Imported 3rd party library from SBT can't find package

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.6

I'm using Play 2.6 with Scala - but this may not be a Play issue.

I've built the project using SBT, and found a lovely [CSV file reader library](https://github.com/tototoshi/scala-csv) I wanted to use in my project. So I import it into my build.sbt as follows:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq("com.github.tototoshi" %% "scala-csv" % "1.3.4")
```

And do a refresh project. I go to use one of its static methods in a class of mine, and IntelliJ suggests an auto-import, which I add to the class:

```
import com.github.tototoshi.csv.CSVReader

class MyClass { ... }
```

But when I go to compile this via `localhost:9000` in the browser, I get this error:

```
object github is not a member of package com
```

I'm new to using 3rd party libraries, but how can it not find the imported library? It told me where to find it, so it's in there somewhere. Should I change anything?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

It was a Play issue. I was trying to run my application from the browser - from my understanding the application compiles itself when you try to load your application after making changes.

Comment: Call `show libraryDependencies` from SBT console

Comment: Can you post your build.sbt?

Comment: @SelvaramG sure - this may be easier: https://github.com/NateHan/MScProject_Nhanak/blob/master/trackwild/build.sbt

Comment: @cchantep Sorry - what does this do? I typed `sbt show libraryDependencies` and it gave me this: `Not a valid key: show (similar: showTiming, showSuccess, show-timing)`

Comment: In the SBT console, not from CLI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a Play issue after all. I think SBT needed to do a compile on its own after I took the above steps.

I simply shut down the localhost server I was running from, did a `sbt clean compile run` and that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RootProject` to reference an external build. You can find details and examples here - https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Full-Configuration#project-references.